# Как сравнить два значения тегов Input?

Tags: javascript

```js
function checkDate() {
  var first_1 = document.getElementById('first').value();
  var second_2 = document.getElementById('second').value();
  if (first_1 > second_2) {
    alert("введен неправильный промежуток времени ");
  } else if (first_1 == second_2) {
    alert("введенные даты одинаковы ");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="date"> <input id="second" type="date">
```

Как проверить на корректность два значения тега input, значениями которых являются даты.
Не допустимо использование сторонних фреймов.

Comment: Где ваш html код   ? Какой формат?

Comment: все просто...  берешь и сравниваешь......

Comment: <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<input id="first" type="date" >
<input id="second" type="date"  >

<script type="text/javascript>
function checkDate (){
 var first_1 = document.getElementById('first').value();
 var second_2 = document.getElementById('second').value();
if (first_1 > second_2) {
 alert( "введен неправильный промежуток времени ");}
else if (first_1 == second_2) {
 alert ("введенные даты одинаковы "); }
}
</script>
</body>
<html>

Comment: @Dima научитесь правильно задавать вопросы и форматировать код.

Comment: @Air вот там как раз трудности с "берешь": `...value()`

Comment: @Igor, вообще не соображу о чем ты?  поясни...

Comment: @Air скобочки не нужны

Comment: @Igor, я в курсе, что не  нужны, а кто мне давал право менять код из приведенного примера....????

Answer (score 2):

Без обертывания в Date.parse() -> сравниваются строки.

```
function checkDate() {
   var first_1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById('first').value);
   var second_2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById('second').value);

   if (first_1 > second_2) {
      alert("введен неправильный промежуток времени ");
   } else if (first_1 == second_2) {
      alert("введенные даты одинаковы ");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Не успел добавить вариант)

Answer (score 1):

**.val();** - Используется в Jquery в JS  используется: **.value;**

```js
function checkDate() {
  var first_1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second_2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
    
  var a = Date.parse(first_1);
  var b = Date.parse(second_2); 
 
  if (isNaN(a)){
    alert("не число!");
    return;
  }else{
   if (a.toLocaleString() > b.toLocaleString() ||
      a.toLocaleString() < b.toLocaleString()) {
    alert("введен неправильный промежуток времени ");
   }else if (a.toLocaleString() == b.toLocaleString()) {
    alert("введенные даты одинаковы ");
   } 
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="date"> 
<input id="second" type="date">

<input type="button" value="Сравнить" onclick="checkDate()">
```

Правильнее наверное будет вот так:

*С первичной проверкой*

```js
function checkDate() {
  var first_1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second_2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
    
  var a = Date.parse(first_1);
  var b = Date.parse(second_2); 
 
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){
    alert("не число!");
    return;
  }else{
   if (a.toLocaleString() > b.toLocaleString() ||
      a.toLocaleString() < b.toLocaleString()) {
    alert("введен неправильный промежуток времени ");
   }else if (a.toLocaleString() == b.toLocaleString()) {
    alert("введенные даты одинаковы ");
   } 
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="first" type="date"> 
<input id="second" type="date">

<input type="button" value="Сравнить" onclick="checkDate()">
```

Comment: И как, интересно, сравнятся даты в строковом представлении?

Comment: @Igor сейчас посмотрим

Comment: пардон, беру свои слова обратно

Comment: @Igor что думаете ? *второй вариант